# Make a game from a TV game show

Tags: copyright, trademark, intellectual-property

I'm an indie developper and I'm planning to do a game based on a TV game show. I would like to know if I could have problems with the law if I do it. I know I should consult a lawyer but I can not afford to do it. For example, can I make a game called "Ninja Warrior, the game", and try to reproduce the game show? Since this isn't a copy of an existing video game, but an adaptation of a game show, I'm confused of what I can do or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Lawyers can give you the specific legal advice for your situation that you need to proceed. If you can’t afford one now, you can’t afford this business venture since you won’t be able to afford a lawyer when action is taken against you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use anything that is subject to copyright, trademark, patent, et cetera without permission.

TV show titles are typically trademarks, so using them is potentially treading on dangerous ground. If your game is similar enough to the Ninja Warrior show that one could make a case that somebody would confuse your product for theirs, you will likely lose any resulting legal action.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I will find a new idea, thanks for the help.